# Input string was not in a correct format. when load brand combobox from category combobox

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I'm facing problem when try to load brand combobnox when selecting category from category combobox. I get an error:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

My code:

```
private void CategoryComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        BrandTB brnd = new BrandTB();
        brndobj = new BrandBAL();
        BrandComboBox.DataSource = brndobj.LoadBrandCombobox(brnd).Tables[0];
        brnd.CategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(CategoryComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString());
        BrandComboBox.DisplayMember = "Brand";
        BrandComboBox.ValueMember = "ID";
}
```

Comment: Likely that `CategoryComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString()` returns a value that cannot be represented as an integer, what is its value?

Comment: CategoryComboBox have DisplayMember=Name and ValueMember =ID

Comment: When i hover mouse on CategoryCombBox its showing Count 2 and on .SelectedValue showing nothing